# URL RewriteRule doesn't work when using WP Database Participants in my WordPress website

Tags: url, wordpress, url-rewriting, plugin

I'm using WP Participants Database plugin in a site developed using WordPress and I'm trying to transform:

`http://example.com/subfol1/subfol2/?listpage=3&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc#participants-list`

into:

`http://example.com/subfol1/subfol2/3/`

My .htaccess is the one below:

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/([0-9]+)/?$ ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/?listpage=$1&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc#participants-list [NC,L]
```

My last `RewriteRule` does not rewrite the ugly URL. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work as in visiting the clean URL doesn't pull up the correct content, or as in the plugin isn't linking to the clean URLs?

Comment: The WP Database Participants plugin isn't linking to the clean URL However, the content is OK because I can navigate through all the pages inside the website showing my database records.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the order of your rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

needs to be the *last* rewrite rule.    It rewrites *all* URLs and is marked as last.   No rewrite rule that comes after it is going to have a chance of working.

Try moving your `produse` up near the rewrite rule that adds a trailing slash to the admin page.

Comment: I've swapped the last two rewriting rules considering your correct observation but it continues to show me the ugly URL.

Comment: rewrite rules won't prevent the ugly URL from working or from being linked to.   They only make the pretty URL work *too*.  Does the pretty URL at least work now?

Comment: Only http://mysite.com/subfol1/subfol2/. URL http://mysite.com/subfol1/subfol2/2/ is still shown in the ugly form.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen has already stated, the order of the directives needs to be changed... the "catch-all" rewrite needs to be last.

However, there are few other things to consider...

> My last `RewriteRule` does not rewrite the ugly URL.

The last `RewriteRule` attempts to *internally rewrite* the "pretty" URL back to the "ugly" URL. This is required (although there are problems with it - see below). However, there is no code here that rewrites (or rather, *redirects*) the "ugly" URL as is suggested. Ideally, the "pretty" URL should be generated by your application, not in .htaccess.

> `RewriteRule ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/([0-9]+)/?$ ^produse/piese-schimb-utilaje-agricole/?listpage=$1&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc#participants-list [NC,L]`

You need to remove the `^` prefix from the `RewriteRule` substitution - this is a string, not a regex. You also need the `NE` (`noescape`) flag, otherwise the special chars in the substitution (the `#` in this case) will be escaped (percent encoded).

> is still shown in the ugly form.

As mentioned above, the "pretty" URL should be generated by your application. To catch "ugly" URLs that have been indexed you can *externally redirect* requests for the "ugly" URL to the "pretty" URL. Note, however, that if you are still linking to the "ugly" URL in your application then this will result in an *external redirect* everytime a user follows a link on your site - which is not desirable.

Something like the following near the top of your script (before the *internal rewrites*):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(subfol1)/(subfol2)/\?listpage=(\d+)&search_field=none&value=&operator=LIKE&sortBy=denumire&ascdesc=asc&submit=&sortstring=denumire&orderstring=asc
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

Check against `THE_REQUEST` in order to avoid a rewrite loop (resulting from the *internal rewrite* back to the "ugly" URL).